# ListView Blank After Calling AsyncTask doInBackground

Tags: android, listview

i have an adapter for my listView, and the data populating from internet,
The Background Process is running good, the Result Appear in Log Cat but no in  My List View, What the problem here ? am I doing wrong? here is my Code

```
PortalGroup mPortalGroup;
ArrayList<PortalItemData> mItems;
PortalItemListAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_group);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    new MyPortal().execute();
        mItems = new ArrayList<PortalItemData>();
        mAdapter = new PortalItemListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mItems);

        JazzyListView list = (JazzyListView) findViewById(R.id.listGroup);
        list.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        list.setTransitionEffect(new FlyEffect());

}

private class MyPortal extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,Void> {
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(GroupActivity.this);
        pDialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener(){

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                MyPortal.this.cancel(true);
            }
        });
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Portal portal = AccountManager.getInstance().getPortal();
        try {
            PortalInfo portalInfo = portal.fetchPortalInfo();
            List<String> querys = portalInfo.getFeaturedGroupsQueries();
            for (String query : querys) {
                Log.d("Query Group", "[query] " + query);
                PortalQueryResultSet<PortalGroup> result = portal
                        .findGroups(new PortalQueryParams(query));
                for (PortalGroup group : result.getResults()) {
                    Log.d("Available Group", "[group title] " + group.getTitle());
                    PortalQueryParams queryParams = new PortalQueryParams();
                    queryParams.setQuery(PortalItemType.WEBMAP, group.getGroupId(), null);
                    PortalQueryResultSet<PortalItem> results = portal.findItems(queryParams);
                    for (PortalItem item : results.getResults()) {
                        Log.d("Group Item", "[item title] " + item.getTitle());
                        byte[] data = item.fetchThumbnail();
                        if (data != null) {
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                            PortalItemData portalItemData = new PortalItemData(item, bitmap);
                            mItems.add(portalItemData);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            pDialog.dismiss();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            onError(e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Toast.makeText(GroupActivity.this, getString(R.string.failed_sign_in), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
         mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

private class PortalItemListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PortalItemData> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public PortalItemListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PortalItemData> items) {
        super(context, 0, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_group, parent, false);
        }

        // Setup item thumbnail
        PortalItemData item = getItem(position);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        image.setImageBitmap(item.itemThumbnail);

        // Setup item title
        TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        text.setText(item.portalItem.getTitle());
        return convertView;
    }

}


private class PortalItemData {
    PortalItem portalItem;

    Bitmap itemThumbnail;

    public PortalItemData(PortalItem item, Bitmap bt) {
        this.portalItem = item;
        this.itemThumbnail = bt;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is some issues, you are setting the adapter in **onPreExecute()**, thats why the problem arising.

Comment: I have tried to put in OnCreate but the problem still same

Comment: onPostExecute write **mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()**, it will solve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried setting your listview in your main activity?

Comment: Yes I Have, and also i have addd mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in onPostExecute(), but the problem still there.

Comment: But here in onPostExecute(), you have not specified anything.

Comment: What if you put 
mAdapter = new PortalItemListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mItems); list.setAdapter(mAdapter); in onPostExecute()?

Comment: Would You Like to give me simple code, i have add in code, i will update my Question.

Comment: Whether its working now?

Comment: Nope, same as Before

Answer (score 0):

In `onPostExecute` you might want to populate your `ListView`.

Instantiate your `Adapter` i.e. mAdapter in `doInBackground` once you have fetched the values of `mItems`. Finally set the `Adapter` to the `ListView` in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: I have done that, and the result listView is Still Blank

Comment: By blank, do you mean there are no rows or the content of the rows are blank?

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions

- either add `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` on `onPostExecute()`
- create the adapter in `onPostExecute()`  and set it to the `Listview`

your current code can actually cause an `Exception` in certain scenarios

Answer (score -1):

Use Below code

```
private class MyPortal extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,Void> {
ProgressDialog pDialog;
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(GroupActivity.this);
    pDialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener(){

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            MyPortal.this.cancel(true);
        }
    });
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();
}

protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Portal portal = AccountManager.getInstance().getPortal();
    try {
        PortalInfo portalInfo = portal.fetchPortalInfo();
        List<String> querys = portalInfo.getFeaturedGroupsQueries();
        for (String query : querys) {
            Log.d("Query Group", "[query] " + query);
            PortalQueryResultSet<PortalGroup> result = portal
                    .findGroups(new PortalQueryParams(query));
            for (PortalGroup group : result.getResults()) {
                Log.d("Available Group", "[group title] " + group.getTitle());
                PortalQueryParams queryParams = new PortalQueryParams();
                queryParams.setQuery(PortalItemType.WEBMAP, group.getGroupId(), null);
                PortalQueryResultSet<PortalItem> results = portal.findItems(queryParams);
                for (PortalItem item : results.getResults()) {
                    Log.d("Group Item", "[item title] " + item.getTitle());
                    byte[] data = item.fetchThumbnail();
                    if (data != null) {
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                        PortalItemData portalItemData = new PortalItemData(item, bitmap);
                        mItems.add(portalItemData);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        pDialog.dismiss();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        onError(e);
    }
    return null;
}

public void onError(Throwable e) {
    Toast.makeText(GroupActivity.this, getString(R.string.failed_sign_in), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    pDialog.dismiss();
}

protected void onPostExecute() {
    list.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    list.setTransitionEffect(new FlyEffect());
    pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

}

Comment: Try it once and let me know if you face any problem..!

Comment: i have tried, and `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()` come out